# KL divergence between two datasets with different length using scipy

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to calculate KL divergence using the entropy function of scipy.
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.entropy.html

```
from scipy.stats import entropy
data_a = np.array([176,489,7])
data_b = np.array([84,86,47,18,99,26,50,53,76,27])
entropy(data_a, data_b)
```

I got the following error. How should I do?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-d8fef5634e56> in <module>
----> 1 en = entropy(data_real, data_crowd)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py in entropy(pk, qk, base)
   2548         qk = asarray(qk)
   2549         if len(qk) != len(pk):
-> 2550             raise ValueError("qk and pk must have same length.")
   2551         qk = 1.0*qk / np.sum(qk, axis=0)
   2552         vec = rel_entr(pk, qk)

ValueError: qk and pk must have same length.
```

I use MacOS 10.14.5, python 3.7.2 and scipy 1.2.1.

Comment: The returned error is pretty clear: `data_a` and `data_b` must have the same length.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Can I calculate KL divergence between two datasets with different length?

Comment: Are your datasets going over the same range of the random variable ? Otherwise the KL divergence is not even defined

Comment: Thank you for your information. My datasets are
 data_a = np.array([176,489,7])
and
data_b = np.array([84,86,47,18,99,26,50,53,76,27]). I understand that  KL divergence is not even defined.